# Flutter || google_maps_flutter package free?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

does the google maps api from cloud.google only unlock if you pay or make billing account ? i want to enable the android sdk but it ask me to make billing account to access it.

if it does only unlock with billing account, do you have any other suggestion ?

[image]

it's redirect me to make billing account, the problem is i don't have any card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google map api is free for android and ios platform.
it will not charge you.
but you need to add billing account.

Comment: how ?? i get redirect to make billing account when i choose google maps platform, i edited the question, you can see the image